# regex to remove number (year only) from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I know the regex that separates two words as following:

input:

```
'WonderWorld'
```

output:

```
'Wonder World'

"WonderWorld".replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1');
```

Now I am looking to remove number in year format from string, what changes should be done in the above code to get:

input

```
'WonderWorld 2016'
```

output

```
'Wonder World'
```

Comment: You should use `.replace(/([A-Z][a-z]+)(.+)/g, '$1 $2');` for separating two words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the location before an uppercase letter (but excluding the beginning of a line) with `\B(?=[A-Z])` and match the trailing spaces if any with 4 digits right before the end (`\s*\b\d{4}\b`). In a callback, check if the match is not empty, and replace accordingly. If a `match` is empty, we matched the location before an uppercase letter (=> replace with a space) and if not, we matched the year at the end (=> replace with empty string). The four digit chunks are only matched as whole words due to the `\b` word boundaries around the `\d{4}`.

```js
var re = /\B(?=[A-Z])|\s*\d{4}\b/g; 
var str = 'WonderWorld 2016';
var result = str.replace(re, function(match) {
  return match ? "" : " ";
});
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>'" + result + "'</pre>";
```

A similar approach, just a different pattern for matching glued words (might turn out more reliable):

```js
var re = /([a-z])(?=[A-Z])|\s*\b\d{4}\b/g; 
var str = 'WonderWorld 2016';
var result = str.replace(re, function(match, group1) {
  return group1 ? group1 + " " : "";
});
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>'" + result + "'</pre>";
```

Here, `([a-z])(?=[A-Z])` matches *and captures into Group 1* a lowercase letter that is followed with an uppercase one, and inside the callback, we check if Group 1 matched (with `group1 ?`). If it matched, we return the `group1` + a space. If not, we matched the year at the end, and remove it.

Comment: The solution I suggest is based on assumptions, same as yours. Mine assumes that the year at the end of the string (4-digit number) should only be removed. If not, `$` should be replaced with `\b`. This is a **one regex solution**, I just add *alternation* with the help of a `|` operator. All replacements are done when processing *one* regex and it is thus a 1-regex pass.

Comment: Its workable solution, I changed $ with \b to pass on 'WonderWorldGoodHlu 0000 FrankyDrank', thanks

Comment: Thank you for precising, I updated the answer to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
"WonderWorld 2016".replace(/([A-Z])|\b[0-9]{4}\b/g, ' $1')
```

Comment: @bureaquete I've modified it to be one regex

Comment: 'WonderWorldGoodHlu 0000 FrankyDrank' fails your regex

Answer (score 1):

How about this, a single regex to do what you want:

```
"WonderWorld 2016".replace(/([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z].*)\s.*/g, '$1 $2');
"Wonder World"
```

get everything apart from digits and spaces.

Comment: What about `WonderWorld NEW!`? It does not end with a year, but the `NEW` will get removed. See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/bG3fR8/1) - this solution doesn't work. Please fix.

Comment: No, `'WonderWorld 2016a'` works perfectly with my solution -> `'Wonder World 2016a'`. The final `2016a` is not removed because it is not a year. A year is a 4 digit number, not a string of alphanumerics. Your solution remove *everything* that is at the end. @Zeeschan: Are you sure it is what is required?

Comment: your regex works only for 2 strings its not generic, btw thanks.

Answer (score 0):

re-code of @Wiktor Stribiżew's solution:

`str` can be any "WonderWorld 2016" | "OneTwo 1000 ThreeFour" | "Ruby 1999 IamOnline"

```
str.replace(/([a-z])(?=[A-Z])|\s*\d{4}\b/g, function(m, g) {
  return g ? g + " " : "";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

import re

remove_year_regex = re.compile(r"[0-9]{4}")

[Test regex expression here](https://regex101.com/r/gL2nF3/1)